WebClient request not working after converting from Rest Template
I'm having an issue converting this piece of code below to WebClient. I'm planning to convert it to WebClient as recommended by this doc https://www.baeldung.com/rest-template and I think it is more suitable as it is asynchronous.
Rest Template
HttpHeaders requestHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
            requestHeaders.add(Constants.AUTHORIZATION, Constants.AUTH_TOKEN_TYPE_BEARER + token);
            requestHeaders.add(Constants.HEADER_ENV, "it01");
            requestHeaders.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
            requestHeaders.setAccept(Arrays.asList(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));
            //String bodyString = safeObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(wlsMemoRequest);
            HttpEntity<String> requestEntity = new HttpEntity<>(bodyString, requestHeaders);

            logger.info("createWlsMemo url : " + url);
            logger.info("createWlsMemo requestEntity : " + requestEntity.toString());

            ResponseEntity<CreateWlsMemoResponse> responseEntity = restTemplate.exchange(url, HttpMethod.POST, requestEntity, CreateWlsMemoResponse.class);
            HttpStatus statusCode = responseEntity.getStatusCode();
            logger.info("createWlsMemo statusCode: " + statusCode);

I tried to convert it to WebClient as shown below
WebClient
WebClient webClient = WebClient.builder()
                    .defaultHeaders(httpHeaders -> {
                        httpHeaders.add(Constants.AUTHORIZATION, Constants.AUTH_TOKEN_TYPE_BEARER + token);
                        httpHeaders.add(Constants.HEADER_ENV, "blahblah");
                        httpHeaders.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
                        httpHeaders.setAccept(Arrays.asList(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));
                        logger.info("httpHeaders: " + httpHeaders); //same object as above
                    })
                    .build();

            Mono<CreateWlsMemoResponse> createWlsMemoResponse = webClient.method(HttpMethod.POST)
                    .uri(url)
                    .bodyValue(wlsMemoRequest)
                    .exchangeToMono(response -> {
                        if (response.statusCode().equals(HttpStatus.OK)) {
                            logger.info("CreateWlsMemoResponse part");
                            return response.bodyToMono(CreateWlsMemoResponse.class);
                        }
                        else {
                            logger.info("Error encountered here!");
                            throw new CreateMemoException("Error encountered Here!");
                        }
                    });


But I'm always receiving timeout issue when using WebClient but I am receiving success response when using RestTemplate. Can someone help out? Thanks!

You have to use block or subscribe get the result. see also https://reflectoring.io/spring-webclient/

Hello, I tried it with either and also tried it with jsonplaceholder but I'm receiving same issue. Here is snippet of error.
Encounter exception while calling CreateWlsMemoRestSvcClientImpl","level":"ERROR","stack_trace":"org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.WebClientRequestException: Connection timed out: no further informatio
n: jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/104.21.59.19:443; nested exception is io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AnnotatedConnectException: Connection timed out: no further information: jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/104.21.59.19:443\r\n\ta
t

The following example should work
WebClient webClient = WebClient.builder()
        .defaultHeaders(httpHeaders -> {
            httpHeaders.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
            httpHeaders.setAccept(Arrays.asList(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));
        }).build();

Mono<String> entityMono = webClient.post()
        .uri(new URI("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts"))
        .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
        .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
        .body(BodyInserters.fromValue("{}"))
        .exchangeToMono(r -> {
            if (r.statusCode().is2xxSuccessful()) {
                return r.bodyToMono(String.class);
            } else {
                return r.createError();
            }
        });
System.out.println(entityMono.block());

